# mailx bcc cc options null hanlde

Tags: shell, variable-substitution

I am using below command for sending email, it working only if all parameter supplied.

Please advise how to handle null/blank variable. For example, if -c -b is not supplied then ignore.

```
mailx -a ${ATTACH} -s "$SUBJECT" -c "$CC_MAIL" -b "${BCCMAIL}" -r "${FROM}" "${TO_LIST}"
```

Regards,
Veera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

> `${parameter:+word}`
>
> If *parameter* is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of *word* is substituted.

```
mailx ${ATTACH:+-a} "${ATTACH}" ${SUBJECT:+-s} "$SUBJECT" ${CC_MAIL:+-c} "$CC_MAIL" ${BCCMAIL:+-b} "${BCCMAIL}" ${FROM:+-r} "${FROM}" "${TO_LIST}"
```

Example:

```
echo mailx ${ATTACH:+-a} "${ATTACH}" ${SUBJECT:+-s} "$SUBJECT" ${CC_MAIL:+-c} "$CC_MAIL" ${BCCMAIL:+-b} "${BCCMAIL}" ${FROM:+-r} "${FROM}" "${TO_LIST}"
ATTACH=foo
echo mailx ${ATTACH:+-a} "${ATTACH}" ${SUBJECT:+-s} "$SUBJECT" ${CC_MAIL:+-c} "$CC_MAIL" ${BCCMAIL:+-b} "${BCCMAIL}" ${FROM:+-r} "${FROM}" "${TO_LIST}"
SUBJECT=bar
echo mailx ${ATTACH:+-a} "${ATTACH}" ${SUBJECT:+-s} "$SUBJECT" ${CC_MAIL:+-c} "$CC_MAIL" ${BCCMAIL:+-b} "${BCCMAIL}" ${FROM:+-r} "${FROM}" "${TO_LIST}"
```

prints

```
mailx
mailx -a foo
mailx -a foo -s bar
```